# Reporting contrasts between binary probability parameters in Bayesian data analysis - odds ratios or difference in probability?

Tags: logistic, bayesian, binary-data, hierarchical-bayesian

In a bayesian data analysis, if one is modeling differences in binomial/bernoulli probability parameter differences between populations, is it still standard to report the difference in the binary probability as an odds ratio / relative risk as opposed to a probability difference? Take for example, estimating a set of binomial proportions and computing posterior contrasts between them via a beta-binomial model.

The use of the odds ratio in the context of logistic regression makes sense since there's a direct correspondence between the coefficient and the change in the log odds ratio. However, in Bayesian data analyses, I commonly see the posterior distribution shown on a 0-1 scale and the posterior contrasts on the same scale as a posterior distribution.  What's the preferred scale on which to present binary probability contrasts in a Bayesian data analysis (and why is it preferred)?

Comment: I realize it's pretty straightforward to do transformations on the posterior samples (odds, log odds, risk ratios, etc), the question is regarding the preferred/standard presentation.

Comment: In my case, there are several comparisons on different scales, but I'd like to present results in a uniform way. My impression is posteriors are often presented on a 0-1 scale (makes sense since the model is on that scale), but it's awkward to present the results as such when most of the literature is based on logistic regression and presents odds ratios.

Is there not a consensus on how to present such results in Bayesian data analyses, or perhaps bda practitioners simply don't care what transformations are made to the posterior (I'm not asking rhetorically - this is a possible answer)?